# How to split q1 data into months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have one doubt in sql server:

in my table have 4 querter related totalamt values is available.
here I want split q1 sum values to months (april,may,june) of current year and 
q2 sum values to months (july,Aug,Sep) of current year
q3 sum values to months (Oct,Nov,Dec) of current year
q4 sum values to months (Jan,Feb,Mar) of current year if i run current months are (jan or feb or mar ) then consider year as current year else next year of current year.

table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[task](
    [Vertical] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [q1] [money] NULL,
    [q2] [money] NULL,
    [q3] [money] NULL,
    [q4] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[task] ([Vertical], [AccountName], [q1], [q2], [q3], [q4]) VALUES (N'BFSI', N'susse', 90.0000, 15.0000, 30.0000, 6.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[task] ([Vertical], [AccountName], [q1], [q2], [q3], [q4]) VALUES (N'BFSI', N'AIG', 100.0000, 50.0000, 40.0000, 60.0000)
GO
```

based on the above data I want output like below :

```
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| vertical | accountname | reveune |   month   | year |
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
| BFSI     | AIG         | 13.3333 | December  | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 13.3333 | November  | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 13.3333 | October   | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 16.6666 | August    | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 16.6666 | July      | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 16.6666 | September | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         |   20.00 | Feburary  | 2019 |
| BFSI     | AIG         |   20.00 | January   | 2019 |
| BFSI     | AIG         |   20.00 | March     | 2019 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 33.3333 | April     | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 33.3333 | June      | 2018 |
| BFSI     | AIG         | 33.3333 | May       | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    2.00 | Feburary  | 2019 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    2.00 | January   | 2019 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    2.00 | March     | 2019 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    5.00 | August    | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    5.00 | July      | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |    5.00 | September | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   10.00 | December  | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   10.00 | November  | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   10.00 | October   | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   30.00 | April     | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   30.00 | June      | 2018 |
| BFSI     | susse       |   30.00 | May       | 2018 |
+----------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

---

I tried like below:

```
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q1]/3  as reveune , 'April' as month  ,year(getdate())as year from task 
union 
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q1]/3 revenue ,'May' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q1]/3  as reveune , 'June' as month  ,year(getdate())as year from task 
union 
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q2]/3 revenue ,'July' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q2]/3 revenue ,'August' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q2]/3 revenue ,'September' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union 
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q3]/3 revenue ,'October' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q3]/3 revenue ,'November' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q3]/3 revenue ,'December' as month,  year(getdate())as year from task 
union
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q4]/3 revenue ,'January' as month,  
case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end  year from task
union 
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q4]/3 revenue ,'Feburary' as month,  
case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end  year from task 
union 
select  vertical ,accountname ,[q4]/3 revenue ,'March' as month,  
case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end  year from task
```

above query is giving expected result .but its taking very long time .can you please tell me any alternative solution 
to achieve this task in sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the desired output with `cross apply`:

```
select Vertical, AccountName, x.v as revenue, x.m as month, x.y as year
from [dbo].[task]
cross apply (values 
     (q1/3, 'April'    , year(getdate()))
    ,(q1/3, 'May'      , year(getdate()))
    ,(q1/3, 'June'     , year(getdate()))
    ,(q2/3, 'July'     , year(getdate()))
    ,(q2/3, 'August'   , year(getdate()))
    ,(q2/3, 'September', year(getdate()))
    ,(q3/3, 'October'  , year(getdate()))
    ,(q3/3, 'November' , year(getdate()))
    ,(q3/3, 'December' , year(getdate()))
    ,(q4/3, 'January'  , case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end) 
    ,(q4/3, 'February' , case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end) 
    ,(q4/3, 'March'    , case when datepart(mm,getdate())=1 then datepart(yyyy,getdate()) else  datepart(yyyy,getdate())+1 end) 
    ) x(v,m,y)
```

*Note: I'm not sure if the association between months and quarters is actually correct, but this is just an implementative detail, you should be able to quickly fix it*